# How to define a custom no-op special form type

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I need something that behaves as follows:

```py
NoOp = ...  # don't know how to define this

def foo(bar: NoOp[int]) -> int:
    return bar + 1

foo(1)
```

I want mypy to treat `bar` exactly as if I had simply annotated it as `bar: int`. I also need it to be distinct from `int` itself in order to write code that checks if something was annotated with e.g. `NoOp[str]` vs just `str`. It's just mypy that should treat them the same.

---

I tried to work with [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) to get something similar, but since it treats the resulting definition as a subclass it didn't work for my purposes, and the way I had to use it also created code that was very hard to read.

Comment: is NoOp just a synonym for int then?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos No, I added some more explanation to the post

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/5eb703d443296f534eca47d3d9095a9f) is something very close to my actual use case. I didn't include this long example because I thought it has too much information that isn't relevant to the question itself, maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I still don't understand what's stopping you from using `str`.  Is there a type-level difference between `NoOp[str]` and `str`?  Do you want to actually do `NoOp` instance checks, and if so is there a reason you don't define a `NoOp` wrapper class?

Comment: Oh, I messed up in my example. For `isinstance` checks on the value itself, there should be no difference between a `NoOp[type]` and `type`, but when inspecting the annotation of a value, there should be a difference - so a simple alias wouldn't do. I can fix the example tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `NoOp[T]` and `T` are exactly the same type both at runtime and also in the eyes of the type checker. The only difference is that you want to write custom code that inspects the annotations, and be able to tell `T` apart from `NoOp[T]`. Is this correct?

If so, then you could check out the [`Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) type, introduced in Python 3.9 and backported via `typing_extensions`. It takes the form of `Annotated[T, X]`, where `T` is a type annotation and `X` is arbitrary metadata. It allows you to associate the metadata `X` with annotation `T`, while not changing the type (i.e. `Annotated[T, X]` is equivalent to `T`).

For your case, you could define `NoOp` as a generic type alias:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
NoOp = Annotated[T, "no-op"]  # use "no-op" as metadata, but you could just choose any value

def foo(bar: NoOp[int]) -> int:
    return bar + 1
```

You can then inspect the annotations with [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) (replace `typing` with `typing_extensions` for versions prior to 3.9). The annotation object will have a `__metadata__` attribute, which holds a tuple of the metadata:

```
>>> typing.get_type_hints(foo)  # by default it strips the metadata
{'x': int, 'return': int}

>>> typing.get_type_hints(foo, include_extras=True)
{'x': typing.Annotated[int, 'no-op'], 'return': int}

>>> x_annotation = typing.get_type_hints(foo, include_extras=True)["x"]
>>> x_annotation.__metadata__
('no-op',)
```

The reason it's a tuple is because you could associate multiple values with it, e.g. `Annotated[int, "a", "b", 1.234]`.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like just what I want. Until now, I've never come around to understand what `Annotated` does, thanks for the explanation. I'll test it and get back if it works.

Comment: I never got back to tell if it works so.. it did work, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

With some doubts because I am not sure I got your usecase -- sorry if this is not what you need.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')   # you can better specify this if needed

class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(content: T):
    self.content = content


def f(x: Wrapper[int] | int) -> int:
    if isinstance(x, Wrapper): 
        return x.content + 1
    return x + 1
```

If on the other hand you want to make `Wrapper` to behave functorially so that you don't need to do instance checks within `f`, you could do something like

```py
    def __add__(self, other: Wrapper[T] | T):
        if isinstance(other, Wrapper):
            return Wrapper(self.content + other.content)
        return Wrapper(self.content + other)
```

but you'd need to be careful because you'll end up with a non-commutative `__add__` (not necessarily wrong, but something to be aware of).